# Saving Traned AI models In Google Colab

Tags: artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning

After training a twin delayed DDPG agent in Google colab for 10 hours I downloaded the python file to continue the work on another platform. The problem however is that the training data is not included when I save the python notebook file, hence the training data was lost. How can I save the file, move it to for example to the Unity 3D environment without dropping the training so I don't have to re-train the agent.

I sincerely appreciate any answers, comments, thoughts etc!

Answer (score 1):

Store files you want to be persistent across sessions in Drive.

Here's a snippet showing how to mount your Google Drive as a FUSE filesystem in Colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you for the response, will check it out!